# Get full path to files in S3 using Boto3 nested keys

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

My bucket structure is as follows:

```
bucket
    production
        dt=2017-01-01
            file1.json
        ...
        dt=2017-05-01
            file2.json
```

What I'm looking to do is get the full path to file1.json, file2.json, so I can download them.

I'm struggling to do this is python. Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
```

You can list all objects by calling `list_objects`

```
objs = s3.list_objects(Bucket='mybucket')['Contents']
```

Using list comprehension, get the object names ignoring folders (which has a size of 0)

```
[obj['Key'] for obj in objs if obj['Size']]
```

**Or**:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
[key.key for key in bucket.objects.all() if key.size]
```

If you want to list the objects with certain prefix:

```
# S3 list all keys with the prefix 'photos/'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('production')
  for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='2017-01-01/'):
    if obj.size: print obj.key
```

Comment: Ooh! Nice way to ignore zero-length files!

Comment: Thanks but this gets all the files, where as there are scattered files and other directories I don't want to get...how to do that?

Comment: @mr-sk see my update. You can use `filter` for a specific folder.

Comment: How can you list nested directories and not the files they have?

Answer (score 2):

When a list of objects is retrieved from Amazon S3, they Key of the object is always its full path:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for key in bucket.objects.all():
  print key.key
```

Result:

```
production/dt=2017-01-01/file1.json
production/dt=2017-01-01/file2.json
production/dt=2017-05-01/file1.json
production/dt=2017-05-01/file2.json
```

Comment: There are other files in here I want to avoid. This will print them all. How do I limit it to the "dt" directories?

Comment: How about an `if` statement? `if key.key.startswith('production/dt='): print key.key`